# Is "small disk" well-defined?

Tags: manifolds, definition, geometric-topology

I saw the notion "small disk" very frequently used in literature. For example, in *Brunnian braids on surfaces* by V. G. Bardakov, R. Mikhailov, V. V. Vershinin, J. Wu, one line reads:

> Let $P_n(M)$ be the $n$–strand pure braid group on $M$. Let $D^2$ be a small disk in $M$.

(Here $M$ is a compact connected surface.)

I am wondering what on earth is a "small" disk? (Topologically) a disk is a disk, smallness does not make sense to me if there is no metric defined. Even in a metric space, how small is small?

Comment: "Let $\epsilon$ be a small positive number, then there exists a sufficiently large natural number $n$ such that $1/n<\epsilon$." I think the "small" can probably be dropped altogether, just like in my previous statement. But the idea is that we are really interested about what happens when $\epsilon$ gets small, in some intuitive sense, i.e. the tail behaviour of $1/n$.

Comment: Yeah, I roughly agree with @Raskolnikov.  My guess is that the objects they are defining are unambiguously defined once the disk is small enough ( ie. the definition depends on the disk, but there is some disk such that the object defined using any subdisk is isomorphic in a natural way ). This can be made precise at the expense of making the definition more technical.  Disclaimer: I have not read this paper.

Comment: "Small" should probably be read as "sufficiently small," which is well-defined in the absence of a metric (it means "pass to an open disk inside this disk as necessary").

Comment: @QiaochuYuan at the risk of confusing the matter, I'm not sure that is well defined.  For one, I'm not sure "disk" is defined without a metric, but we could certainly replace disk with something like open connected set, or something like that.  Also, though, it's not clear that "passing to an open disk inside this disk as necessary" is a process that terminates.   All my complaints here are surmountable, but I feel like they are important at some, possibly philosophical, level.

Comment: A disk is an open subset homeomorphic to an open disk in $\mathbb{R}^n$. It's not a question of whether some process terminates or not: it's that there is implicitly an existential quantifier surrounding all subsequent statements that looks like "there exists a sufficiently small disk such that..."

Comment: that makes sense for 'disk'. i think the implicit quantifier is stronger than that, though.  i think it's that there is a sufficiently small disk such that ... and the structure remains isomorphic if we take a subdisk.  but maybe this is implicit when we say 'sufficiently'?

Answer (score 1):

If you actually look at the paper, there is no content to the word *small* here. It is purely for flavor, i.e. a suggestion to the reader on how to visualize this disk.

---

There are cases in which a statement of this sort is shorthand for something both meaningful and precise, such as "for all $x \in M$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that for all disks $D \subset U$ containing $x$ $\ \ldots$" (exactly what statement is intended is hopefully clear from context in these cases).